# Tic-Tac-Toe with Single and Multiplayer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

So basically I am trying to build a Tic-Tac-Toe game with both single and multiplayer difficulty levels but I am stuck on what code should I write for player vs computer and I am stuck in a forever loop in the **def play_game()** function. I can't keep the previous stats of the game as well.  I really need help with this.

```
# --------- Global Variables -----------

# Will hold our game board data
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

# Lets us know if the game is over yet
game_still_going = True

# Tells us who the winner is
winner = None

# Tells us who the current player is (X goes first)
current_player = "X"


# ------------- Functions ---------------

# Play a game of tic tac toe
def play_game():

  # Show the initial game board
  display_board() 
  game_on = True  

  while True: 
     print("1.Single Player") 
     print("2.Multiplayer")
     print("3.Game Stats")
     print("4.Quit") 
    
     input_1 = int(input("Please Select An Option"))
    
     if input_1 == "3" :
        print('reading database...')
        read_log()
    
     elif input_1 == "4" :
      exit()
     elif input_1 == "2" :
      
      Player_1 = input("Enter First Player Name:") 
      Player_2 = input("Enter Second Player Name:") 
      display_board() 
      
      

     while game_on: 
      position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ") 
      
      check_for_winner() 
      
      display_board() 


  # Loop until the game stops (winner or tie)
     while game_still_going: 
    
      

    # Handle a turn
      handle_turn(current_player)

    # Check if the game is over
      check_if_game_over()

    # Flip to the other player
      flip_player()
  
  # Since the game is over, print the winner or tie
      if winner == "X" or winner == "O":
        print(winner + " won.")
      elif winner == None:
        print("Tie.")


# Display the game board to the screen
def display_board():
  print("\n")
  print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + "     1 | 2 | 3")
  print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + "     4 | 5 | 6")
  print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + "     7 | 8 | 9")
  print("\n")


# Handle a turn for an arbitrary player
def handle_turn(player):

  # Get position from player
  print(player + "'s turn.")
  position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")

  # Whatever the user inputs, make sure it is a valid input, and the spot is open
  valid = False
  while not valid:

    # Make sure the input is valid
    while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
      position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")
 
    # Get correct index in our board list
    position = int(position) - 1

    # Then also make sure the spot is available on the board
    if board[position] == "-":
      valid = True
    else:
      print("You can't go there. Go again.")

  # Put the game piece on the board
  board[position] = player

  # Show the game board
  display_board()


# Check if the game is over
def check_if_game_over():
  check_for_winner()
  check_for_tie()


# Check to see if somebody has won
def check_for_winner():
  # Set global variables
  global winner
  # Check if there was a winner anywhere
  row_winner = check_rows()
  column_winner = check_columns()
  diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()
  # Get the winner
  if row_winner:
    winner = row_winner
  elif column_winner:
    winner = column_winner
  elif diagonal_winner:
    winner = diagonal_winner
  else:
    winner = None


# Check the rows for a win
def check_rows():
  # Set global variables
  global game_still_going
  # Check if any of the rows have all the same value (and is not empty)
  row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-"
  row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "-"
  row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "-"
  # If any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
  if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
    game_still_going = False
  # Return the winner
  if row_1:
    return board[0] 
  elif row_2:
    return board[3] 
  elif row_3:
    return board[6] 
  # Or return None if there was no winner
  else:
    return None


# Check the columns for a win
def check_columns():
  # Set global variables
  global game_still_going
  # Check if any of the columns have all the same value (and is not empty)
  column_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != "-"
  column_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != "-"
  column_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != "-"
  # If any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
  if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
    game_still_going = False
  # Return the winner
  if column_1:
    return board[0] 
  elif column_2:
    return board[1] 
  elif column_3:
    return board[2] 
  # Or return None if there was no winner
  else:
    return None


# Check the diagonals for a win
def check_diagonals():
  # Set global variables
  global game_still_going
  # Check if any of the columns have all the same value (and is not empty)
  diagonal_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "-"
  diagonal_2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "-"
  # If any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
  if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
    game_still_going = False
  # Return the winner
  if diagonal_1:
    return board[0] 
  elif diagonal_2:
    return board[2]
  # Or return None if there was no winner
  else:
    return None


# Check if there is a tie
def check_for_tie():
  # Set global variables
  global game_still_going
  # If board is full
  if "-" not in board:
    game_still_going = False
    return True
  # Else there is no tie
  else:
    return False


# Flip the current player from X to O, or O to X
def flip_player():
  # Global variables we need
  global current_player
  # If the current player was X, make it O
  if current_player == "X":
    current_player = "O"
  # Or if the current player was O, make it X
  elif current_player == "O":
    current_player = "X"

def read_log():
    log = open('log.txt', 'r')
    log.seek(0)
    print('\n\n')
    print(log.read(),'\n\n')

# ------------ Start Execution -------------
# Play a game of tic tac toe

play_game()
```

Comment: Please fix indentation.

Comment: You have an endless loop ` while game_on: ` and I see no place where you set game_on to False. So it won't stop.

Comment: Are you asking how to choose a computer move?  That's the only challenge in a tic-tac-toe application.  You can certainly block any potential wins.

Comment: From the option menu you get user input with `input_1 = int(input("Please Select An Option"))` - so `input1` is an integer - but you then compare it against text characters, which will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly You can do it like this:

**Define functions:**

```
handle_player_move()

handle_computer_move()
```

as names suggests when you call the function either human player or computer will make a move (make sure that it's certain or add some Errorcodes/Exceptions when player do something unexpected and you want to end program)

**Define function:**

```
game_is_over() # returns True if it's the end of game False other wise
```

Then Your game is just:

Human vs Human:

```
whos_move = 0   # number of player ( 0 or 1 )
while not game_is_over():
     if whos_move == 0:
         handle_player_move(player1)
     if whos_move == 1:
         handle_player_move(player2)
     whos_move = (whos_move + 1) % 2
```

Quite similarly Human vs Bot:

```
whos_move = 0   # number of player ( 0 or 1 )
while not game_is_over():
     if whos_move == 0:
         handle_player_move(player1)
     if whos_move == 1:
         handle_computer_move(player2)
     whos_move = (whos_move + 1) % 2
```

Instead of this you can also check for end of game with your function, and do:

```
whos_move = 0   # number of player ( 0 or 1 )
while game_still_going:
     if whos_move == 0:
         handle_player_move(player1)
     if whos_move == 1:
         handle_computer_move(player2)
     whos_move = (whos_move + 1) % 2
     check_if_game_over()
     if statement:  # your ending statement here
         game_is_still_going = False
```

Your method with flip_player() is also good I just put if statements to both so that they are familiar in truth if you would are able to distinguish in handle_turn() between bot and human player you can do it for both cases ;)

As implementing computer moves can be hard here are some tips:

Easiest way you can just randomly choose number between 1 and 9 check if it's unoccupied if it's free computer makes move there if it is not you pick again. Maybe it sounds like being potentially endless loop but statisticly computer shouldn't have any problems with making a move.

You can also create list of free squares and then randomly choose an index (probably better way)

You can also try to add some logic f.e. if there are two in a row block third square.

too choose random integer from given interval you can use:

```
import random
random.randint(1,9) # choose integer x such that: 1 <= x <= 9
```

Of course you can and even maybe should use your own function names (name them as you wish!)

Hope that helps, good luck!